# Consistency and timeout issues with Cassandra 2.2

Tags: cassandra, timeout, consistency, cassandra-2.2

I'm using Cassandra 2.2 and I've an application that requires a high level of consistency.

I've configured one datacenter cluster with 3 nodes.
My keyspace is created with `replication_factor` of 2.
In each configuration.yaml files I've set 2 seed_providers (for example NODE_1 and NODE_3).

**The important thing is that my app should be full-functional even if one node is down.**

Currently I've some issues with the consistency and timeout when my app contacts the cluster.

I've read the whole Cassandra 2.2 documentation and I concluded that the best `CONSISTENCY LEVEL` for my write operations should be `QUORUM` and for my read operations `ONE`, but I still have some consistency issues.

First of all, is it the right choice to have a strong level of consistency?
And also, are `UPDATE` and `DELETE` operations considered as write or read operations, since for example an update operation with a `WHERE` clause still has to 'read' data? I'm not sure, spacially in the context of the cassandra' write workflow.

My second issue is the timeout during the write operations. A simple and lightweight `INSERT` sometimes get "`Cassandra timeout during write query at consistency QUORUM (2 replicas were required but only 1 acknowledged the write)`"
or sometines even "... 0 acknoledged" even though all of my 3 nodes are UP.

Are there some other parameters that I should check, like for example write_request_timeout_in_ms, with default value of 2000 ms (which is already a high value)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You will have strong consistency with `Replication Factor = 2` and `Consistency Level = QUORUM` for write operations and `ONE` for read operations. But write operations will fail if one node is down. `Consistency Level = QUORUM` is the same as `ALL` in case `Replication Factor = 2`.

You should use `Replication Factor = 3` and `Consistency Level = QUORUM` for both write and read operations, to have strong consistency and full functional app even if one node is down.

`DELETE` and `UPDATE` operations are write operations.

For the timeout issue please provide table model and queries that fails.

**Updated**

Consistency level applies to replicas, not nodes.

Replication factor = 2 means that 2 of 3 nodes  will contain data. These nodes will be **replicas**.

QUORUM means that a write operation must be acknowledged by 2 **replicas** (when replication factor=2), not nodes.

Cassandra places the data on each node according to the partition key. Each node is responsible for a **range** of partition keys. Not any node can store any data, so you need have alive replicas (not nodes) to perform operations. Here article [about data replication and distribution](https://docs.datastax.com/en/cassandra/2.1/cassandra/architecture/architectureDataDistributeAbout_c.html).

When you perform QUORUM write request to cluster with 2 of 3 alive nodes, there is a chance that the cluster has only 1 alive replica for the partition key, in this case the write request will fail.

In additional: here is a [simple calculator for Cassandra parameters](http://www.ecyrd.com/cassandracalculator/)

Comment: Thank you for you answer. But, could you explain please, just a little bit, why having 3 nodes at the start with the replication factor 2 will make the write operations fail if one node fails. With one failed node I still have 2 nodes available. In my mind, in this case writing with QUORUM consistency (2 replications must be aknowledged) should still work. But I'm probably wrong. Thank you.

Comment: @TheWingman, I've added explanation about replication to my answer

Comment: Thank you very much for all these explanations. It's much more clear

Comment: Could you please take a look on my second post http://stackoverflow.com/q/40953885/7183762. I would really appreciate it. Thank you.