# Handle different restore scenarios with Cassandra 2.2

Tags: backup, restore, cassandra-2.2

I have a Cassandra 3-node cluster and a keyspace created with a `replication_factor` of 3.

I make my backups for this keyspace with `nodetool snapshot`. As recommended by Cassandra documentation, to make a global backup I start it with a cron job on each node (3 nodes are NTP synchronized). I'm not using incremental snapshots, it's always a new global snapshot.

Unfortunately, I've some troubles with the restore process.

First of all, I've set a replication factor to 3 (and `QUORUM` level of consistency on READ and WRITE operations) to make sure my app keeps working even if 1 node is down.

- My first scenario is not really a restore process: 
  one node goes down because of, let's say the someone or something shutdown the VM that the node was running on. The 2 others nodes keep working and receiving write/read requests. 24 hours later, I manage to restart the VM of the first node, all services and files are still there, and I'm about to restart the node.
  **Are there any actions that I should do before or after the restarting?**
- Second scenario is pretty much the same, but I was not able to recover the VM of the first node and I need to reinstall everything on it, including Cassandra.
  **How should I use my backup to resync this node? Should I even use it or is Cassandra capable to resync everything without me having to restore anything? What should I do precisely in this case?**
- My last scenario is different. I've lost all my nodes and cannot recover anything. I've my global snapshot (3 snapshots, 1 for each node, taken at the same time). **What is the process in this case?**

I've read the Cassandra documentation for the restore process, and I've a preference for the simple copy-restore (in other words, I rather not use `sstableloader`). I've troubles to understand when I should use `refresh` and/or `repair` commands in those scenarios.

Answer (score 1):

> I've troubles to understand when I should use refresh and/or repair commands in those scenarios

According to [documentation](http://docs.datastax.com/en/cassandra/3.0/cassandra/operations/opsBackupSnapshotRestore.html) you should perform `refresh` when you restore data from a snapshot, the 2nd and the 3rd scenarios.

I suppose repair is not required step for all three scenarios. But I would recommend perform it because it is easy and useful step to have consistent data on just restored nodes.

Furthermore `repair` on a regular basis is a recommended part of cassandra cluster maintenance.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. But in case of the first scenario, after restarting the node that was shutdown for few hours or days, should I do something else, beside `nodetool repair`? And for the second one, should I use my snapshot from the lost node or is Cassandra capable of resync everything by itself using the 2 other nodes?

Comment: @TheWingman, Repair is enough for the first scenario, even the node was down for a long time. And for the second one, Cassandra can bootstrap data  from other nodes (http://cassandra.apache.org/doc/latest/operating/topo_changes.html#bootstrap) but it can take long time compared to restoring from snashot.